# Elasticsearch bool filter query return results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with mappings:

```
[test] => Array
    (
        [mappings] => Array
            (
                [testype] => Array
                    (
                        [properties] => Array
                            (
                                [brand_id] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => integer
                                    )

                                [color] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => string
                                        [index] => not_analyzed
                                    )

                                [description] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => string
                                    )

                                [discount] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => float
                                    )

                                [newprice] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => float
                                    )

                                [oldprice] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => float
                                    )

                                [sex] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => string
                                        [index] => not_analyzed
                                    )

                                [store_id] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => integer
                                    )

                                [title] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => string
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

And trying to filter my data with this query:

```
Array
(
[index] => test
[type] => testype
[size] => 100
[body] => Array
    (
        [query] => Array
            (
                [filtered] => Array
                    (
                        [filter] => Array
                            (
                                [bool] => Array
                                    (
                                        [must] => Array
                                            (
                                                [term] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [brand_id] => 53
                                                        [color] => red
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Expecting to get result like SELECT ... WHERE brand_id=53 AND color=red, but have results like brand_id=53 OR color=red. Am i'm missing something?

Actualy, i want to have a filter like SELECT ... WHERE aaaa='a' AND bbbb='b' AND cccc IN (1,2,6,9) AND ddd IN (xxx,yyy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the terms in different arrays.

Disclaimer: I guess this syntax is the PHP one, I'm not familiar with it, please forgive any syntax error.

Try this:

```
[must] => Array
    (
        [term] => Array
            (
                [brand_id] => 53
            )
        [term] => Array
            (
                [color] => red
            )
    )
```

Your last query should look like this:

```
[must] => Array
    (
        [term] => Array
            (
               [aaaa] => 'a'
            )
        [term] => Array
            (
                [bbbb] => 'b'
            )
        [terms] => Array
            (
                [cccc] => Array(1, 2, 6, 9)
                [minimum_should_match] => 1
            )
        [terms] => Array
            (
                [dddd] => Array('xxx', 'yyy')
                [minimum_should_match] => 1
            )
    )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, thats works for me. Can i ask you to explain, what if i don't provide [minimum_should_match] => 1, because it's work without it, as it seems to me.

Comment: You're right, the default value of `minimum_should_match` seems to be 1. But I prefer to set it explicitly to avoid confusion.